# Superposition of 2 voltage sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, superposition

I’m trying to do superposition of this circuit. If I try to redraw the circuit by 20V, are 5 ohms and 2 ohms in series? I try to redraw like this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I2 is fake news.  The 4 ohm (1/4 siemens conductance) resistor is simply in parallel with the 2 ohm (1/2 siemens) resistor.  *In parallel, conductances simply add*, so they serve as a 3/4 Siemens (4/3 ohm) resistor.  Simplify any?

Comment: @jsotola, the bottom 2 ohms. I forgot to specify

Answer (score 2):

Not quite - a picture speaks a thousand words:

[image]

When 10V is nulled by superposition, it becomes a short circuit, connecting markers D and E.

The two-ohm resistor on the right of your diagram is suspect - the original schematic has 2-ohm resistors linking C-E and A-E, while your diagram has a two-ohm resistor linking C-E (which looks correct) and the one on the right side (which seems misplaced).

There should be one linking A-E (in parallel with the 4-ohm resistor), and D and E need to be linked directly (since you shorted the 10-V source).

In general, identifying nodes and elements with concrete names (e.g. node A, resistor R3) will help you keep track of everything that's going on, and mentally translate from one diagram to another.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I try to redraw the circuit by 20V, are 5 ohms and 2 ohms in
> series?*

The 5 Ω is **parallel** to a 2Ω resistor when the 10 volt source is replaced with a short circuit: -

[image]

The lower 2 Ω resistor is not in series with either but, it is in parallel with the 4 Ω resistor as previously stated in an earlier answer.